# requests in Python I am trying to login to website using library

Tags: python, python-requests, python-requests-html

this is my code

```
import requests
s = requests.session()
login_url = 'https://edvgerial.kapitalbank.az/az/login'
s.headers.update({"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"})
csrf_token=s.get(login_url).cookies.get('_csrf')
payload = { 
    "loginMethod":"PIN", 
    "pin": "My_pin", 
    "password":"My_password", 
    "_csrf": csrf_token
}
res=s.post(url=login_url, data=payload)
print(res.text)
```

And the response the website gave me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /az/login</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I was undecided when choosing the login method

Comment: If you want to be able to interact with the login page, I think you'd be better off running a headless browser with something like [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/). If you do wish to use requests, you will need to look into any APIs the website provides, since that'll make interacting with the site's data much easier.